# On existence of finitely generated projective generator with commutative endomorphism ring in ${}_R Mod$

Tags: homological-algebra, modules, abelian-categories, projective-modules

Let $R$ be a ring with unity (not necessarily commutative). Let ${}_R Mod$ be the category of left $R$-modules. If ${}_R Mod$ has a projective generator with commutative endomorphism ring , then does ${}_R Mod$ have a finitely generated projective generator with commutative endomorphism ring ?

Comment: I still don’t know the answer, but I raised exactly the same question in a comment on this MSE question some time ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364337/abelian-category-induced-by-commutative-ring. It would be interesting to know whether your interest in the question is for similar reasons.

Comment: @JeremyRickard: I just saw your comment in the linked question ... and yes I was also thinking about how to distinguish the category of modules over a commutative ring from that over  a general ring ..